# set url when set cookie with ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have script that set cookie with ajax, but it doesn't works.

I think it's because of the site location/url.

The site doesn't have domain yet and it's running on my local pc:
http://localhost/my-site/index.php

```
$(document).on("click", ".change_lang", function(e){

var lang = $(this).attr("data-lang");
var info = 'lang=' + lang;       


$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax/change_lang.php',
  data: info,
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
      if (data == "true") {
          alert ("<?PHP echo $_COOKIE['user_lang'] ?>");
          location.reload();
      }
  }
}); 
e.preventDefault();
});
```

AJAX FILE:

```
if (setcookie("user_lang", $_POST['lang'], time()+3600*24*365, "/"))
    echo "true";
else
    echo "false";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to send a request to save a cookie, those are available from the client too: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp